# How to deploy a KQL function to ApplicationInsights using bicep savedSearches

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics, azure-bicep

Using Bicep I can deploy KQL queries and function to a Log Analytics workspace using

```
resource azLogAnalyticsWorkspace 'Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces@2021-06-01'
existing = {
  name: 'my-la'
}

resource kqlHealthQuery1 'Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/savedSearches@2020-08-01' = {
  name: 'myHealthFunction'
  parent: azLogAnalyticsWorkspace
  properties: {
    category: 'Health'
    displayName: 'My First Function'
    functionAlias: 'MyFirstFunction'
    query: loadTextContent('./Sample.kql')
    tags: [{name: 'type', value: 'health' }]
  }
}
```

This function shows up on the tab Functions, under "Workspace functions".

Now I would like to use these KQL functions to query Application Insights tables like traces and exceptions. But when I open Log Analytics and change the scope to my Application Insights instance, I no longer see the functions. I only see a folder "Component functions" with just one function that I saved manually from the UI.

How can I use Bicep to deploy a KQL function so that it shows up in the "Component functions" with Application Insights?

Comment: I think you need to use `microsoft.insights/components/analyticsItems`. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.insights/components/analyticsitems?pivots=deployment-language-bicep

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, didn't know that one but it looks promising.

When I try:
```
resource myFunction 'microsoft.insights/components/analyticsItems@2015-05-01' = {
  name: 'item'
  parent: azAppInsights
  Scope: 'shared'
  Id: 'b402c7ed-0c50-4c07-91c4-e975694fdd32'
  Content: loadTextContent('./Tasker/MySampleFunction.kql') 
  Properties: {
    functionAlias: 'MySampleFunction'
  }
}
```

I get the following error:
'Could not find member 'Content' on object of type 'TemplateResource'.

Seems similar to the Github issue:
https://github.com/Azure/bicep-types-az/issues/1847

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the issue with Bicep, I decided to try it with Terraform. That works as expected, using code like below.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~>2.0"
    }
  }
  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name  = "my-poc"
    storage_account_name = "mypocstorage"
    container_name       = "tfstate"
    key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
  }
}

# Azurerm Provider configuration
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "parent_group" {
  name = "my-poc"
}

data "azurerm_application_insights" "myAi" {
  name = "my-ai"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.parent_group.name
}

# Create a set of all KQL files in the directory.
locals {
  kql_files = fileset(path.module, "./myFiles/*.kql")
}

# Create a function for each file
resource "azurerm_application_insights_analytics_item" "myAiFunc" {
  for_each = local.kql_files

  application_insights_id = data.azurerm_application_insights.myAi.id
  type = "function"   # must be query, function, folder or recent
  name = "item"
  scope = "shared"
  function_alias = substr(basename(each.value),0, length(basename(each.value))-4) 
  content = file(each.value)
}
```

Just save it to main.tf and run

```
terraform init
terraform plan
terraform apply
```